# spring-boot guide 'Accessing data with MySQL' to derby

Tags: spring-boot, derby

I go through ['Accessing data with MySQL'](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) and everything goes well.

Then, I want to change db from MySQL to derby. So I

1. change dependencis from MySQL to derby in pom.xml
2. change jdbc-url from MySQL to derby in `resources/application.properties`

Finally I run and got:

```
2017-04-27 20:43:29.502 ERROR 7121 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table user (id integer generated by default as identity, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
2017-04-27 20:43:29.503 ERROR 7121 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Syntax error: Encountered "user" at line 1, column 14.
```

I think and think, finally find that problem is that an entity named User(User.java) in this guide. maybe 'user' is something like keyword that cannot be used as table name in derby. evidence is here:

```
ij version 10.13
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:derdb';
ij> create table user(i int);
ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "user" at line 1, column 14.
ij> create table iuser(i int);
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
```

So I suggest to change the guide to avoid this unhappy thing.

Comment: This is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your table name from 'user' to any other name.